# Convert Jboss (WildFly) cli output to json in Ansible

Tags: python, ansible, command-line-interface, wildfly

I'm struggling to automate my deployment processes to WildFly over its cli. The cli itself don't work idempotent, so if I want to add using ansible for example some server properties it just threw an error in case it already exist (official cli documentation gives only 3 methods add, read, remove https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/CLI+Recipes - no replace or force add). So I need to create some conditions before, and the easiest is ready (just if exists):

Ansible code:

```
- name: Check Server Runtime properties
  shell: ./jboss-cli.sh --commands="connect {{ wf_server }},/core-service=platform-mbean/type=runtime:read-attribute(name=system-properties)" $AUTH_DATA
  args:
    chdir: "{{ wf_path }}/bin"
  register: srp_chk
- name: Configure Some properties
  shell: ./jboss-cli.sh --commands="connect {{ wf_server }},/system-property={{ item.mkey }}:add(value=\"{{ item.mval }}\")" $AUTH_DATA
  args:
    chdir: "{{ wf_path }}/bin"
  when: "not '{{ item.mkey }}' in srp_chk.stdout"
  with_items:
   - { mkey: some.property1, mval: "{{ some_value1 }}" }
   - { mkey: some.property2, mval: "{{ some_value2 }}" }
```

It works fine till the case when I need to change some_value1 or some_value2. In that case as you can get, I need to delete properties and create again.

So we are almost near my question :)

I know that these values could be found in srp_chk.stdout and I can create the same check for ex:

```
when: "not '{{ item.mval }}' in srp_chk.stdout"
```

BUT in case I have more complex structure and I need to compare two jsons in Ansible?

**Thats where my question begins** :))

In my example srp_chk.stdout have Jboss cli output in Json format but in one line, and unfortunatelly when I try Jinja2 filter "from_json" it gives errors:

```
the field 'args' has an invalid value ([]), and could not be converted to an dict
```

"to_json" and "to_nice_json" gives some strange unreadable data and error:

```
template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'outcome'.
```

"outcome" - is content of my string.

So, I have variable srp_chk.stdout_lines which is more readable in terms of json formatting and have something like this:

```
"stdout_lines": [
            "{", 
            "    \"outcome\" => \"success\",", 
            "    \"result\" => {", 
            "        \"PID\" => \"76462\",", 
            "        \"[Standalone]\" => \"\",", 
            "        \"awt.toolkit\" => \"sun.awt.X11.XToolkit\",", 
            "        \"some.property1\" => \"some.value1\",", 
            "        \"some.property2\" => \"some.value2\",",
```

etc. but its list.

**QUESTION:
How can I convert this list to json data so in Ansible I can get "some.value1" from variable "srp_chk.stdout_lines.result.some.property1" ?**

P.S. Please don't advise to always delete and add properties, because on each deploy I'll need to reload my server - which is pretty bad case when we are talking about PROD.

Comment: Your sample data is no way even close to JSON syntax. You should try to find way to fetch data as JSON. Google suggests [this](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/pull/2903/files#diff-c019b5da214851e92f20e3089d4e5fe6R94) and [this](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-script/managing-jboss-wildfly-using-httpjson-api)

Comment: Curl actually is not an option, the only allowed way to get data from WildFly is CLI, but yeah I've managed to change symbol '=>' to ':' and get more like Json format& trying to convert it, thanks for tip.

Answer (score 3):

Next version of WildFly (aka 12) will support outputting to JSON https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-3363

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a very simple and crude Ansible module in shellscript using sed to convert jboss-cli output to JSON and provide it as facts.

You can use this to obtain the JBoss configuration data already as facts, thus allowing the use of them in the "when" conditionals, instead of trying to make Ansible parse the output as JSON (which it is not, as directly outputted by jboss-cli). Or you can check the text substitutions done to convert that output to JSON (crudely) and use it in other ways.

In case you find it useful, it's here:

https://github.com/spuk-/jbossclifacts